# iOS onTouchMove x or y axis

Tags: javascript, ios, touch

I'm trying to prevent the default iPhone scrolling function on the x-axis only. I have a gallery that works via the onTouchMove event to slide photos left to right. Currently it employs the prevent default function like so:

```
function onTouchMove(e) {
            if(config.preventDefaultEvents) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
```

This is working fine but it prevents the iPhone default scrolling on the y-axis too. Is there any way to make the preventDefault specific to x-axis TouchMove event, thus making my gallery scroll up and down the screen naturally?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe your context: Are you referring to a UIWebview?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this approach:

```
lastx = event.touches[0].clientX;
lasty = event.touches[0].clientY - canvastop;
```